# (CSS/Bootstrap 4) Add a cell to a specific table column

Tags: html-table, bootstrap-4

I have this table of input fields and was wondering how to add new "cells" to specific columns. Just like this:
[image]

Is there a way to do this by simply adding a new `<tr>`. Or do I have to do this by adding input fields with labels outside of a `<table>` element. If I go this route, is there Bootstrap/CSS stylings I could add to "attach" these fields to those table columns so they would resize with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you can just add a new row. Use the `colspan` attribute on the `td` to specific how many column the cell will span. In your case, your first cell that contains "TOTAL" will span across 6 cells, which will be like `<td colspan="6">TOTAL</td>`, and apply some some css styles to remove the border and align the text to the right.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

th, td {
  min-width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
}

td.total {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.no-border {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="total">
    <td colspan="6" class="total no-border">TOTAL</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="total no-border">TOTAL</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="no-border"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="6" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
                <th></th>
<th colspan="1" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
<th colspan="2" style="text-align:right"></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
```

then please see this code
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html